# Gear 2 - Privileges SecurityError when using IRLED

Tags: tizen, infrared, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I'm developing an application that controls a device with IRLED.

In the Tizen Wearable SDK, I have a button that, when clicked, the should run the following script:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('tester').onclick = function() 
{
    var data = "SOME InfraRED CODES !!!!";
    webapis.irled.send(
        data,
        function() {
            console.log("data send ok");
        }, 
        function(e) {
            console.log("Error: " + e.message);
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

The application runs without any errors on mu Gear 2 (SM-R380), but when I tap the button, the following error appears in the console:

```
js/main.js (17) :SecurityError: The application does not have the privilege to call this method.
```

I've also added [the IRLED privilege](http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/irled) in the `config.xml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should to get a Certificate From samsung developer , and then store the `certificate-registration.xml` in your **/home/developer** on your device .

in this process you need the DUID and you can get it by your device properties !

for more information about CSR (Certificate Signing Request) follow this link :

[Samsung Gear Development](http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-gear)

also you can get extra and more informations in :

**Tizen IDE For Wearables > Help > Help Contents > Getting Started with Tizen Wearable > Development Environment > Tizen SDK for Wearable > Certificates**

hope for the day we see you app in Samsung App Store !